# Ansible Lookup formatting

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to configure a Prometheus server with Ansible. To do so, I have put the configuration in a file, which I read via lookup:

```
prometheus_scrape_configs: "
{{ lookup('file', 'files/prometheus/prod/scrapes/basic.yml') }}
"
```

The file contains a standard configuration:

```
- job_name: "prometheus"
  metrics_path: "{{ prometheus_metrics_path }}"
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - "{{ ansible_fqdn | default(ansible_host) | default('localhost') }}:9090"
 [...]
```

However I get an output like this:

```
+  " ---\n- job_name: \"prometheus\"\n  metrics_path: \"{{ prometheus_metrics_path }}\"\
+    \n  static_configs:\n    - targets:\n        - \"{{ ansible_fqdn | default(ansible_host)\
+    \ | default('localhost') }}:9090\"\n-
```

With '\n' printed instead of interpreted. I'm not sure what is the issue.

Changing the lookup to :

```
{{ lookup('file', 'files/prometheus/prod/scrapes/basic.yml')|from_yaml }}
```

yields a list:

```
+ ' [{''job_name'': ''prometheus'', ''metrics_path'': ''{{ prometheus_metrics_path }}'', + ''static_configs'': [{''targets'': ["{{ ansible_fqdn | default(ansible_host) | default(''localhost'') + }}:9090"]}]}, {''job_name'': ''node'', ''honor_labels'': True, ''ec2_sd_configs'': + [{''region'': ''eu-west-1'', ''port'': 9100, ''profile'': ''prometheus-ec2-read-only'', + ''filters'': [{''name'': ''tag:monitoring'', ''values'': [''prometheus'']}]}], ''relabel_configs'': [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the YAML text to the list, e.g given the simplified data

```yaml
shell> cat basic.yml 
- key1: val1
  key2: val2
  key3: val3
```

the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: ps_configs
      vars:
        ps_configs: "{{ lookup('file', 'basic.yml')|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ps_configs:
  - key1: val1
    key2: val2
    key3: val3
```

Comment: Strange: it seems to be translating it to JSON: +  ' [{''job_name'': ''prometheus'', ''metrics_path'': ''{{ prometheus_metrics_path }}'',
+    ''static_configs'': [{''targets'': ["{{ ansible_fqdn | default(ansible_host) | default(''localhost'')
+    }}:9090"]}]}, {''job_name'': ''node'', ''honor_labels'': True, ''ec2_sd_configs'':
+    [{''region'': ''eu-west-1'', ''port'': 9100, ''profile'': ''prometheus-ec2-read-only'',
+    ''filters'': [{''name'': ''tag:monitoring'', ''values'': [''prometheus'']}]}], ''relabel_configs'':
[...]

Comment: What you see depends on the callback. See ``ansible-doc -t callback yaml``. If you're not sure about the internal representation of data see [type_debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#discovering-the-data-type). Do not put code into the comments. Instead, [edit] question and put relevant [mre] there.

Comment: Sorry about the code, I edited my question. The type_debug helped me to find out it was actually a list! It seems my file is considered "AnsibleUnsafeText", not sure why. I'm also not sure it's really the Callback, since it's what Ansible is trying to write in the file.